# JavaScript function deleteCookie() is not working for me

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

I am trying to learn JavaScript and got hung up on trying to create a button that deletes a cookie, but my code simply is not working and I have been stuck on this for hours now.

For convenience, the page is hosted here: 
http://kazmer.x10host.com/Week4/delete_cookie_test.html

The cookie.js is located here: 
http://kazmer.x10host.com/Week4/cookies.js

The code in the external cookies.js is the following:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days, path, domain, secure) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    cookieString = name + "=" + escape (value);
    if (expires) cookieString += "; expires=" + expires;
    if (path) cookieString += "; path=" + escape (path);
    if (domain) cookieString += "; domain=" + escape (domain);
    if (secure) cookieString += "; secure";
    document.cookie = cookieString;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEquals = name + "=";
    var crumbs = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < crumbs.length; i++) {
        var crumb = crumbs[i].trim();
        if (crumb.indexOf(nameEquals) == 0) {
            return unescape(crumb.substring(nameEquals.length,crumb.length));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The HTML for the page also has some JS in it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en-US">

 <head>
 <title>Delete Cookie Test</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name = "description" content = "JavaScript Test" />

 <script src="cookies.js"></script>

 <script>

    window.onload = function() {
        var cookievalue = prompt("Cookie Value:");
        createCookie("myCookieData", cookievalue);
    }

    function viewCookieInfo() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your cookie value: " + getCookie("myCookieData");
    }

    function deleteCookie(name) {
        name="myCookieData";
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

 </script>

 </head>

 <body>

 <button type="button" onclick="viewCookieInfo()" >Display Cookie Info</button><br>
 <div id="output"></div><br>
 &nbsp &nbsp <button type="button" onclick="deleteCookie()" >Delete Cookie</button>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I understand the concept of expiring the cookie, but it's just not working and I hope someone will point out my error(s) here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include ALL relevant code in your actual question (paste the code right into the question).  Questions that only have external links to relevant code here are not allowed.

Comment: try `0` for the expiry time.

Comment: [MDN: Simple cookie framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework)

Comment: I gave the links to where it is hosted to make it easier for people to see what's going on, but if I posted it all here as well. I tried it with 0 for the expiry time, but still it does nothing. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: I just realize that there was nothing wrong with my code. I just needed to refresh the page to show that the cookie had been deleted. I suppose I could have the deleteCookie function also refresh the page to clear the cookie, but other than that it works fine. I was about to lose my mind with this. Thank you!